# data dimension of scikit learn linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I just started using Python scikit-learn package to do linear regression. I am confused with the dimension of data set it required. For example, I want to regress `X` on `Y` using the following code

```
from sklearn import linear_model
x=[0,1,2]
y=[0,1,2]
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit (x,y)
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
```

System returned with error : tuple index out of range.
According the scikit-learn website, effective arrays should be like

```
x=[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]
y=[0,1,2]
```

(http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares)

```
from sklearn import linear_model
x=[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]
y=[0,1,2]
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit (x,y)
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
```

so it means that package can not regress `X[i]` on `Y[i]` for two single numbers? it must be an array on a number? like `[0,0]` in `X` to `0`in `Y`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can.
Simply reshape your data to be `x = [[0], [1], [2]]`.

In this case , every point in your data will have a single feature - single number.

Comment: yes, I figured it out myself later. X has to be numpy array not list. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Scikit requires your x to be a 2-dimensional array. It need not be a numpy array. You can always use a simple python list.

In case if you have your x as a 1-dimensional array like you just mentioned in your question, you can simply do the following:

```
x = [[value] for value in [0,1,2]]
```

This will store a 2D array of your 1D array in x i.e. every individual value of your list is stored as an array.

Answer (score 0):

`x` can also be converted into a numpy array, and then reshaped as follows:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1)
```

This converts your data into a 2D array so that you can use it for fitting the linear regression model from sklearn.

```
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```